Relationship between integration rule and numerical solution to Fredholm equation with non-unique solutions
In my research (computational physics) I need to solve a Fredholm integral equation of the form
$$ f(x) = g(x,x_i) + \mathcal P \int_0^\infty \frac{g(x,x')}{\tfrac{1}{2}\left(x_0^2-x'^2\right)}f(x') \, dx', $$
where $x_i$ is a fixed parameter, $\mathcal P$ indicates the principle-value integral, and the functions $f$ and $g$ are both real-valued. The function $g$ is evaluated numerically based on the physical problem, and not much can be said about it except that it is symmetric with respect to interchange of its arguments: $g(x,x')=g(x',x)$.
We solve the integral equation by introducing a numerical integration rule with abscissas $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$ and weights $\{w_n\}_{n=1}^N$, leading to
$$ f(x_n) = g(x_n,x_i) + \sum_{m=1}^Nw_m\frac{g(x_n,x_m)}{\tfrac{1}{2}\left(x_0^2-x_m^2\right)}f(x_m), $$
which is further rearranged into a system of linear equations $A\vec x=\vec b$, with
\begin{align}
A_{nm} &= I_{nm} - w_m\frac{g(x_n,x_m)}{\tfrac{1}{2}\left(x_0^2-x_m^2\right)} \\
b_n &= g(x_n,x_i).
\end{align}
The underlying physics dictates that the integral equation does not have a unique solution, except at the point $x=x_0$. That is, every non-unique solution $f(x)$ is guaranteed to pass through the same value at $x_0$. That one value $f(x_0)$ is the only thing we need, so the lack of uniqueness for $x\neq x_0$ is of no consequence in theory, but in practice causes problems with numerical accuracy.
The point $x_0$ does not appear in $\{x_n\}$ since the integral is of principle-value type, with the singularity in the integrand appearing at $x=x_0$, so we extract $f(x_0)$ by substituting the solution back into the integral equation and evaluating the right-hand side with $x=x_0$ in the function $g(x,x')$.
Once we make a choice of integration rule, we are evidently adding some additional constraint to the problem because we end up with a matrix equation which does have a unique solution. I would like to better understand the relationship between the choice of integration rule and the solution we obtain, because the linear system is often highly ill-conditioned, and we are often playing a game of trial and error moving the abscissas around until we get a stable solution.
Here is an example of a pretty good situation where two different choices of abscissas give two different solutions which both want to pass through the same value at $x=x_0$, and the actual difference in the values of $f(x_0)$ due to numerics is relatively small.

But there are often cases where the solution for a particular choice of abscissas will blow up to take on values several orders of magnitude larger than $f(x_0)$ for $x\neq x_0$, and then shoot down with a very large derivative to pass through $f(x_0)$ at $x=x_0$. This creates numerical instability in the quantity $f(x_0)$ we wish to extract, and we can see that these situations coincide with the condition number of the matrix $A$ becoming very large. In principle we can try to improve the conditioning once we already have the matrix $A$ by performing a singular-value decomposition and removing those singular vectors with very small corresponding singular values. But this is a very unsatisfying solution and doesn't work well in practise (often once you remove enough to get a more stable solution you have modified the problem enough to start getting the wrong solution).
It is clear from experience that for a given system there is a choice of abscissa that will give a stable solution, and if we could better understand that relationship then we could choose the abscissa intelligently beforehand. Does anyone have any insight into what is really happening behind the scenes when we pick a particular integration rule which determines which of the non-unique solutions we obtain? And since choosing that integration rule seems to add some additional constrain to the system to pick out just one solution, can we leverage that to add constraints of our choosing? E.g. minimise the derivative at the point $x=x_0$?

Away from the singularity, any quadrature rule should be fine. Within a small region around $x$, say $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, one way is to compute as $$P\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} G(x,x')f(x')dx' \approx f(x) P\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} G(x,x') dx'$$ and compute the integral explicitly.
